# Read dataframe sequentially and change value if duplicate found above

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

EDIT: have edited the post to clarify

So I'm managing a portfolio of project. Each project got its own Excel sheet and I try to track time, cost etc. Problem is that the data look like this:

```
  time cost section error other
0    1  500    lift          E1
1    2  100    lift          E2
2    1  400    wait          E3
3    4  200    lift    D4    E4
4    5  500    lift          E5
5    2  322   crash          E3
6    3  500    lift          E1
7    3  200    wait    D5    E2
```

when I want it to look like this, because I want to distinguish between first lift attempt and the second one:

```
  time cost   section error other
0    1  500      lift          E1
1    2  100      lift          E2
2    1  400      wait          E3
3    4  200  lift (2)    D4    E4
4    5  500  lift (2)          E5
5    2  322     crash          E3
6    3  500  lift (3)          E1
7    3  200  wait (2)    D5    E2
```

Each excel file got between 300-500 lines and some 50 columns so this is just a simple representation.

So I made some code, and honestly what surprises me the most is that me banging rocks together over here actually produces a result. I can’t help wondering though if there is a more beautiful way of doing this.

My code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': ['1', '2', '1', '4', '5', '2', '3', '3'],
    'cost': ['500', '100', '400', '200', '500', '322','500','200'],
    'section': ['lift', 'lift', 'wait', 'lift', 'lift', 'crash', 'lift','wait'],
    'error': ['', '', '', 'D4', '','','','D5'],
    'other': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4', 'E5','E3','E1','E2']}
    )
print(df)
# Check if value in 'section' is identical to value in "cell" above
df['match'] = df.section.eq(df.section.shift())
# If true write section value to new column
df.loc[df['match'] == False, 'match2'] = df['section']
# Check if the value have duplicate further up
df.loc[df['match'] == False, 'match3'] = df.groupby(['match2']).cumcount()+1

# Add an extension to the value based on number of entries
df.loc[df['match3'] == 1, 'match4'] = df['section']
df.loc[df['match3'] == 2, 'match4'] = df['section'] + ' (2)'
df.loc[df['match3'] == 3, 'match4'] = df['section'] + ' (3)'
df.loc[df['match3'] == 4, 'match4'] = df['section'] + ' (4)'
df.loc[df['match3'] == 5, 'match4'] = df['section'] + ' (5)'
df.loc[df['match3'] == 6, 'match4'] = df['section'] + ' (6)'

df['match4'] = df['match4'].ffill()
df['section'] = df['match4']
df.drop(['match', 'match2', 'match3', 'match4'], inplace=True, axis=1 )
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  time cost section error other
0    1  500    lift          E1
1    2  100    lift          E2
2    1  400    wait          E3
3    4  200    lift    D4    E4
4    5  500    lift          E5
5    2  322   crash          E3
6    3  500    lift          E1
7    3  200    wait    D5    E2
  time cost   section error other
0    1  500      lift          E1
1    2  100      lift          E2
2    1  400      wait          E3
3    4  200  lift (2)    D4    E4
4    5  500  lift (2)          E5
5    2  322     crash          E3
6    3  500  lift (3)          E1
7    3  200  wait (2)    D5    E2
```

Comment: sorry - see the guide to [ask] - this isn't a code review or beautification site. if you have a very specific, objective programming question feel free to ask!

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I'll delete the post if you want to. But the answare from mozway is perfect for my problem, so maybe better to keep it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to label the stretches of "lift":

```
# get rows with "lift"
m = df['section'].eq('lift')


n = (df.loc[m, 'section']       # for each "lift"
       .groupby((~m).cumsum())  # group by successive "lift"
       .ngroup().add(1)         # enumerate group
    )

# keep only enumeration > 1
n = n[n.gt(1)]

# add as string between parentheses
df.loc[n.index, 'section'] += ' ('+n.astype(str)+')'
```

output:

```
  time cost   section error other
0    1  500      lift          E1
1    2  100      lift          E2
2    1  400      wait          E3
3    4  200  lift (2)    D4    E4
4    5  500  lift (2)          E5
5    2  322     crash          E3
6    3  500  lift (3)          E1
```

##### generalization to all groups:

```
# groups of successive values
group = df['section'].ne(df['section'].shift()).cumsum()

# get the stretch number per group
n = (group.groupby(df['section'])
          .apply(lambda g: pd.Series(pd.factorize(g)[0]+1,
                                     index=g.index)
                )
    )

# same as above
n = n[n.gt(1)]
df.loc[n.index, 'section'] += ' ('+n.astype(str)+')'

print(df)
```

output:

```
  time cost   section error other
0    1  500      lift          E1
1    2  100      lift          E2
2    1  400      wait          E3
3    4  200  lift (2)    D4    E4
4    5  500  lift (2)          E5
5    2  322     crash          E3
6    3  500  lift (3)          E1
7    3  200  wait (2)    D5    E2
```